# Need help counting characters in an arrayList

Tags: java, arraylist

```
import java.io.* ;
import java.util.ArrayList ;
public class WordSearchPuzzle;
{
    private char[][] puzzle ;
    private ArrayList<String> puzzleWords ;
    private int letterCount = 0 ;
    private int gridDimensions;

    public WordSearchPuzzle(ArrayList<String> userSpecifiedWords)
    {
        this.puzzleWords = userSpecifiedWords ;

    }
    private void createPuzzleGrid()
    {
      int i;
        for(i = 0; i < puzzleWords.size(i).length ; i++){
          letterCount = puzzleWords + letterCount ;
            }
        }
        gridDimensions = letterCount * 1.5;
        puzzle[gridDimensions][gridDimensions];
    }

    public WordSearchPuzzle(String wordFile, int wordCount,
    int shortest, int longest)
    {
        // puzzle generation using words from a file
        // The user supplies the filename. In the file 
        // the words should appear one per line.
        // The wordCount specifies the number of words
        // to (randomly) select from the file for use in
        // the puzzle.
        // shortest and longest specify the shortest
        // word length to be used and longest specifies
        // the longest word length to be used.
        // SO, using the words in the file randomly select
        // wordCount words with lengths between shortest
        // and longest.

    }

    private ArrayList<String> loadWordsFromFile(String filename, int shortest, int longest)
    {
        // BasicEnglish.txt - the 850 words of Basic English
        // BNCwords.txt - "the 6,318 words with more than 800 occurrences in
        //the whole 100M-word BNC"
        try {
            FileReader aFileReader = new FileReader(filename);
            BufferedReader aBufferReader = new BufferedReader(aFileReader);
            String lineFromFile;
            int len ;
            ArrayList<String> words = new ArrayList<String>();
            lineFromFile = aBufferReader.readLine() ;
            while (lineFromFile != null) {  
                len = lineFromFile.length() ;
                if(len >= shortest && len <= longest) {
                    words.add(lineFromFile.toUpperCase());
                }
                lineFromFile = aBufferReader.readLine() ;
            }
            aBufferReader.close();
            aFileReader.close();
            return words ;
        }
        catch(IOException x)
        {
            return null ;
        }
    }

    // The dimensions of the puzzle grid should be set
    // by summing the lengths of the words being used in the
    // puzzle and multiplying the sum by 1.5 or 1.75
    // or some other (appropriate) scaling factor to
    // ensure that the grid will have enough additional
    // characters to obscure the puzzle words. Once
    // you have calculated how many characters you are
    // going to have in the grid you can calculate the
    // grid dimensions by getting the square root (rounded up)
    // of the character total.
}
```

Hi, small Java project I have to do here for college. Here is what I have so far. I don't understand why it's not compiling. I have code written for generating the grid; the grid dimensions are set by the input words (sum of letters of all input words * 1.5). I am not sure of the part which sums all the elements of the Array List together.

What's going on? Thanks in advance :)

Comment: what error does the compiler give?

Answer (score 2):

remove the semi-colon here....  `public class WordSearchPuzzle;`

this isn't a statement.          `puzzle[gridDimensions][gridDimensions];`

`puzzleWords.size(i).length` in the for loop is giving issues.  If you're wanting the number of elements in the list, `puzzleWords.size()` will work.  And then           `letterCount = puzzleWords + letterCount ;`
, you have incompatible types, ArrayList + int, are you meaning to use `puzzleWords.size()` instead of puzzleWords?

Answer (score 2):

I can see multiple problems:

In the class declaration line there should be no semi-colon.

```
public class WordSearchPuzzle
```

As Nettogrof has shown, you have too many }'s in the `createPuzzleGrid` method.

The loop within `createPuzzleGrid` uses methods that do not exist.
There is no `size` method that takes a parameter for array lists. Also it does not find the length of the string at that point
Your loop in `createPuzzleGrid` should be:

```
for (int i = 0; i < puzzleWords.size; i++) {
    String item = puzzleWords.get(i);
    int itemLength = item.length();
    letterCount = letterCount + itemLength;
}
```

As an extra note, the last line of that method accesses the `puzzle` array but does not do anything, so this line could be removed. In fact no methods use the `puzzle` variable so it could be completely removed.

Answer (score 1):

In your createPuzzleGrid,  there's two } in your For-loop

The correctec version:

```
private void createPuzzleGrid()
{
  int i;
    for(i = 0; i < puzzleWords.size(i).length ; i++){
      letterCount = puzzleWords + letterCount ;
    }
    gridDimensions = letterCount * 1.5;
    puzzle[gridDimensions][gridDimensions];
}
```